# QSpinBox thousand separator

Tags: c++, python, qt, pyqt, qspinbox

With a QSpinBox is it possible to display the thousand separator of a number while user enter it
like 10,000
Which is the best way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could subclass `QSpinBox` and reimplement the [`textFromValue`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qspinbox.html#textFromValue) which is responsible for the display of the value to the spinbox widget. A possible implementation could be the following:

```
QString MySpinBox::textFromValue(int value)
{
   return this->locale()->toString(value);
}
```

Using [locale](https://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#locale-prop) is the best way since it will display the separator based on the user's settings.

Comment: it worked , ty , but it do not insert  thousand separator  when user insert a number with keyboard ! when user focus out than that SpinBox then   thousand separator will insert !  how i can fix this ? sory for bad English !

Comment: You could connect the `valueChanged` signal with a custom slot that updates the text. Notice that in this slot you should temproarily block the signals (use `blockSignals(true)`) in order to avoid an endless loop.

Comment: How do you actually update the text like that though?

Comment: How do i subclass? where do i put that code? i put it in the cpp of my QDialog form and it gave me textFromValue does not match any declaration in 'QDoubleSpinBox'

Answer (score 5):

i know this is late but this may help other people. i used this to update the thousand separator

`ui->doubleSpinBox->setGroupSeparatorShown(true);`

or

set the property it in the form ui

[image]

In my QDialog Form i used this to update the amount with thousand separator,

```
void DialogCashPayment::on_doubleSpinBox_valueChanged(double arg1){
     ui->doubleSpinBox->setValue(arg1);
}
```

EDIT:

> Found a bug when amount is 10k above, the cursor position is changed. i don't know how to fix this yet. Maybe someone could fix this.

Comment: Have tested connecting to events on the inherited `lineEdit()` object. Here one can get text-cursor position. Then it is only to compare length of text before and after conversion and re-position the cursor with `setCursorPosition()`