# QSpinBox digit grouping

Tags: c++, qt

I would like to implement (already implemented a scratch but not satisfied with that) a custom `QSpinBox` with the extra feature of a digit grouping. I would like to use this with small and large numbers as well like 1.000 ... 10.000.000. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9274884/qspinbox-thousand-separator) but I think I need a locale independent solution. I'd appreciate any advice.

Comment: "I need a locale independent solution" so you want to always have a `.` to group the digits regardless independent of the locale? Then just format the string in `textFromValue` accordingly.

Comment: A '.' (dot) or a ' ' (space). So that's the only function I need to overwrite ? I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44171440/673852) (still your link, but updated two years after your question was posted).